# How to create a transparent ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

There are two ViewController in this app

ViewController1 --> Present As Popover --> ViewController2

In ViewController2, it set Background to Black Color, and Alpha to 0.1

When the transition of ViewController2 is finish, background will become 1 alpha

How to keep Background of ViewController2 0.1?

Comment: Please show relevant code, that way we can help you better.

Comment: that is a [good material from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621382-popover) to understand popover-presentation-style... briefly: _"In a horizontally compact environment [a.k.a portrait iPhone], this option behaves the same as `fullScreen`."_

Comment: If you post a link just like that without explanation, it looks like spam, so I rolled back your edit. If it isn't spam, please also explain why the link is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For transparent view controller pop up set background of view like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just select your presenting viewcontroller and select the option Over Current Context
and then set background color with some alpha of your presented controller

[image]

Comment: I set to `Over Current Context`, still no different , pls see my video (last sec)

Answer (score 0):

If you present a vie controller modally and gives background colour to clear then it will be transparent until u give some color.

```
    self.present(viewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```